# Can we use Service Endpoints to communicate with a SQL failover group?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

We use UK West as our primary region and UK South as our secondary. We have a database server in West that we created a SQL Failover Group in order to replicate to South.

What I'm looking to know is whether an Application in UK South, can connect to the SQL Failover Group when the the Primary is still West?

I've already tested using a bi-directional VNet Connection, but I'm getting a forbidden request when connecting from South, which leads me to believe the connection is not being used.

`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot open server 'ppd-ons-comet-sql-ukwest' requested by the login. Client with IP address '51.140.146.129' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.`

Comment: I may have found my own answer... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group?tabs=azure-powershell#failover-groups-and-network-security 
Unfortunately this is not the answer I want to hear as we were relying on this approach for more than just the SQL Failover Group!

Comment: Microsoft are replicating the architecture at the moment to see if there is a solution. When they get back to me I'll update here as well.